# Use the same class on several tables with the same structure in subsonic

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, subsonic3

I use Subsonic 3 and found it a really great tool, it helped me a lot!

In my new project I would like to use it not only make mappings in '1 c# class to 1 table mode', but I would like to have a common mapping for several tables with the same structure. To make it clearer: I create tables runtime, structure of this tables are totally the same (note, it must be the same, this tables MUST be seperate ones). Is it possible to have a common mapping between these tables with creating a generic class, by which I can make query operations on all these tables? E.g. this class could have table name as an input parameter, and class makes operations on this table.

Thanks in advance, sorry about my English, I hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible without **extensive** modification to both the templates and the code-base.  Don't fight your tool; if this is what you need SubSonic is the wrong choice.